# How to use X-Rite ColorChecker with Sony a7R IV?

Tags: color-management, white-balance, colorchecker

I purchased an X-Rite ColorChecker to attempt to get better white balance for my camera (a7R IV). My first attempt at using it has yielded wildly questionable results. Process below. All files referenced can be downloaded in the zip archive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H3Fke4QMcin1BqLSSWniGdGl3CV5G1oQ).

1. Shoot image `image.ARW`
2. Use ACR to convert to `image.DNG`
3. Use X-Rite's "ColorChecker Camera Calibration" to create profile `Sony ILCE-7RM4.dcp` from the DNG
4. Open original ARW or DNG in ACR.
5. Change from default profile "Adobe Color" to the custom one I just created.

Results... beyond horrible. See below (Adobe on left, new custom profile on right).  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I can repeat your results, but idk how to fix it, or what went wrong in the first place.

Comment: After further tests. If I repeat your method, as written, from my own camera & Color-Checker, I get the expected result. All I can guess [I'm on Nikon so I have no absolute comparison] is that there's "something" in your original RAW that's upsetting things. I can see nothing wrong with your actual working method. [I know, "something" really isn't helpful, sorry]

Comment: I've gotten the same result using your files. It seems to be screwing with the blue calibration, almost like it was trying to null out the blues. Weird. Do you have the same problem with other calibration images, or is this a one-off problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Move the crop points slightly** so that the squares are better centered in the patches before creating the profile. The problem seems to be associated with the X-Rite color checker autodetection. Even though the squares visually appear to be located within the color patches, part of the border is likely being used to create the profile.

RawTherapee developers provide [guidance](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/How_to_create_DCP_color_profiles) on shooting color calibration targets to create camera profiles.  Notably, do *not* "fill the frame as much as possible", as some here have suggested.  Rather, it's better to:

> Position the target so that it fills the center-third of your frame - not more, not less. The center of the frame has the best optics and lowest vignetting.

The DCamProf developer concurs:

> Uneven lighting is a common problem in camera profiling. The typical recommendation is to make sure you have even lighting (at least two lights if not shooting outdoors) and shoot the target small in the center (to minimize vignetting).

You can also try other software:

- [Adobe DNG Profile Editor](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/digital-negative.html)
- [DCamProf](https://torger.se/anders/dcamprof.html) – open source, command line utility.

Here's the output from RawTherapee with the [standard DCP tone curve](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/File:DCP_tone_curve.rtc) and the following settings:

1. No profile.
2. Camera Standard.
3. DCP file after adjusting crop points.
4. DCP file without moving crop points (autodetect).

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you, this appear to be correct. As a software engineer I've been frustrated with a number of things about the X-Rite software from the moment I first installed it. Add this to the list. Manually centering the squares does appear to yield mostly accurate results. It's annoying though that repeating that process twice does not yield identical results (though they are pretty damn close). $100 for a piece of plastic and some really poorly made software. Aggravating, but hey it's the industry standard. Yay. Thanks for solving the mystery!

Comment: Yup, that makes sense. It's just surprising they can't do a better job of automatically fine-tuning the color square selection (especially since they're able to find the rough area). No worries, still probably the best offering out there, and far better than nothing. Thanks for the other link, might check that out too.

Comment: Thanks much... I will check out the Adobe option right now, because I am officially not happy at all with the X-Rite output. Now that I can get quasi-consistent results, I tried to solve my original problem: removing color cast from ND filter. I had two test shots taken in the same conditions: 1 w/ filter and 1 w/o (both w/ ColorChecker in frame). Creating a profile for each photo did not make them look balanced the same (in fact, neither really looked good). But the Adobe profile for no-filter photo looks good, and with temp/tint alone I can manually make filter photo match.

Comment: Update: the Adobe solution worked like a charm! Quick, easy, and very accurate. Colors look phenomenal, far better than just using stock Adobe profile even for simple shots with no ND filter. I no longer regret buying the passport... seems worth every penny when used with a solid piece of software. Thanks again for the rec, I'd give you another upvote if I could!

Comment: Based on this answer, if you want better, more repeatable results, move over to the passport & just take a picture of it alone. That's what I did with my repro test in comments above & what I do on location too. Get your model [or chair] to hold the passport where you're measuring your light, but just zoom or walk in so there's more passport & less margin for error.

Comment: I had another go at the original image, manually moving the corners. First 6 or 8 attempts the Checker software complained the sample section was too small, reinforcing my point above. The one it did manage to save was better but still not right. Take close-ups in future.

Comment: @xiota I haven't got the Breakout filter yet, it should be arriving soon, I'll compare it to B+W when I get it and update the other post.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah I learned quickly to take larger photos of the passport. Interestingly, I also found a place where the Checker software beats Adobe. I was shooting with heavy ND this weekend, like 30sec exposures. When I held the passport up for large shot, I wanted a quick handheld shot, so I jacked ISO up to max and exposure up to 1/13 sec. The result was (predictably) a blurry and grainy passport. Checker picks it up fine (auto detect), with surprisingly decent results, but Adobe refuses to process it.

Comment: To echo the others: The more that the frame is filled with the color checker, the more consistent your results will be. Just be careful not to shade any of the scene's lighting with the camera (or yourself) when moving in closer to fill the frame as much as possible. If you *must* leave the color checker relatively small in the frame, try to square the edges of the color checker parallel to the edges of the frame, rather than letting it sit at an angle, such as in your test shot. That makes it easier for the software to align with the squares.

Comment: It's *not* advisable to "fill the frame as much as possible".  Light falloff at the edges and corners of the frame will affect the results.  RawTherapee developers [advise](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/How_to_create_DCP_color_profiles) "Position the target so that it fills the center-third of your frame - not more, not less. The center of the frame has the best optics and lowest vignetting."

Comment: @xiota per your comment above, I've started a [new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/117416/which-of-these-nd-filtered-images-do-you-think-is-more-accurate-sample-images) with the results of a new filter test I did. Curious to see what others conclude.